# Cannot enable my local account

Tags: windows-8

Last Friday my account got disabled and windows displayed a message "**the user can't sign in because this account is currently disabled**" when I attempt to login. First I suspected with the company group policies but when talked with the IT they said this is not relevant with them. Later I logged on with another administrator account and tried to enable user through `Computer Management -> Local Users And Groups -> Users`.

I uncheck the "Account is disabled" checkbox in the user properties dialog and apply but it does not anything. When I open the properties dialog again, it is still checked.

Edit:

*Account is not a domain account, a Microsoft User account. I can enable other accounts such as guest but not the one i mention in the question.*

**Solution**

There is a group policy applied by my company which prevent Microsoft Account to log in.

***WindowsSettings-->SecuritySettings-->LocalPolicies-->SecurityOptions-->"Account: Block Microsoft Accounts"***

Comment: You will require `Administrator` active domain permissions to resolve this.

Comment: account is not a domain account, local user account. I  can enable other accounts such as guest but not the one i mention in the question.

Comment: Did you connect this local account to a `Microsoft Account`?  You have to be connected to a domain if you suspected a group policy issue.

Comment: Yes it is connected to a MS account. I have also another account which is connected to company domain. Actually i dont have much information on what group policies can do on my PC, i was suspected that they disabled all local accounts on my PC but now i think that was not the case.

Comment: Can this be about User Profile Service or a corrupted user profile issue? Because after i faced with this problem i tried creating another user and when i tried logging in with the new user i got an error **"the user profile service service failed the sign in. user profile cannot be loaded"**, i fixed that problem following some instructions on MS forums but that did not help the actual problem.

Comment: If its connected to a Microsoft Account then its normal for the local user to be disabled. You should be trying to log into the connected user profile instead. **This behavior is normal** Please update your question with this missing information.  What instructions did you follow exactly?